# Javascript, How to count down attempts and alert after certain number of attempts

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I tried to set a "How Many Finger" game up where the user inputs a number and only has 5 tries to select the same number as the random number. Then after 3 tries , be alerted that you have 2 tries left, then 1left , then game over, try again.  Please don't blast me too hard but my code is set up wrong, I am missing a step somewhere and I am trying to figure out where.

```js
document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {

  //Get a random number between 1 and 5//

  var randomNumber = Math.random();
  randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);

  //Count the number of guesses the user has//
  //User has five attempts to guess correct number//

  var guess;
  var guessCount = 0;
  var numberOfGuesses = 5;
  remainingAttempts = numberOfGuesses--;

  //This is the value of what the user inputs. If the same as random number alert correct// 
  //If random number and user input doesnt match alert incorrect// 

  if (document.getElementById("guess").value == randomNumber) {
    alert("Well done, got it!");
  } else {
    alert("That's not it! Try again");
  }
  remainingAttempts--;

  //Show how many attempts left//

  if (guessCount >= 3); {
    console.log(remainingAttempts + " tries left");
  }

  //two guesses left//
 console.log("Close but no dice." + remainingAttempts + "tries left")

  //1 guess left//
  console.log("Last try")


  //Game over//
  if (guessCount >= 5) {
    alert("No more attempts left.Game Over");
    return;
  }
};
```

```html
<title>How Many Fingers!</title>

<p> Guess how many fingers!</p>

<p><input type="text" id="guess"> <button id="check">Guess!</button></p>
```

Comment: `if (guessCount >= 3);{` <-- issue

Comment: I edited it in your code snippet. It should work now.

Comment: @LloydNicholson this is probably homework; don't make it too easy. @OP, do look at the JavaScript ``switch`` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: game is over when `guessCount >= 5` but I don't see `guessCount` ever increasig